# Documentación Crystal Reports

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

Buen día

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación winforms con Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2013. Está escrita en C#.
Consta de 4 proyectos uno de los cuales contiene los objetos que mapean la base de datos. Estoy tratando de construir el informe basada en Listas de de objetos.
Sin embargo cuando  estoy diseñando el informe no puedo conectarme a objetos .Net que estén fuera del proyecto. 
Alguien sabe como incluir objetos que estén fuera del proyecto donde está el informe?
Otra pregunta. No puedo encontrar información de referencia de Crystal Reports for Visual Studio. Saben si esta información es pública, o se debe comprar.

Gracias por sus respuesta.

Comment: ¿En qué lenguaje estás trabajando en primer lugar? ¿C# o VB.net?

Comment: En c#. Visual studio 2013

Comment: especifica en tu pregunta, editándola.

Comment: No tenes que agregar una referencia al otro proyecto?

Answer (score 0):

Primero, para tener acceso a los modelos (clases, metodos y demas recursos) de otros proyectos dentro de tu proyecto de reportes debes agregar las referencias correspondientes.

En mi ejemplo es un proyecto de UnitTest pero es el mismo procedimiento.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> En el proyecto que deseas tener acceso a los modelos de los demas, expande `References` o `Referencias` si lo tienes en español.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Con el click secundario abre el menu y selecciona `Add Reference` o `Agregar Referencia`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> En esta ventana da click en `Solution` o `Solucion` para buscar los proyectos en tu solucion. Marca la casilla de aquellos proyectos a los que quieres tener acceso, despues da click en `Ok` para terminar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Despues podras ver como tus proyectos aparecen en la lista de `Referencias`

Ahora, en cuanto a informacion sobre Crystal Reports, estos pertenecen a la empresa SAP, en el siguiente link puedes encontrar su [comunidad dedicada a Crystal Reports](https://www.sap.com/community/topic/crystal-reports.html)